# How to set properly the button size in a LinearLayer in Android?

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, alignment

i have the following problem:

I have a horizontal LinearLayout with two buttons, Ok and Cancel. I want the buttons to fill the parent's width, I mean every button 50% (if I had 3 buttons 33% each), buttons have to have the same width BUT when I choose "fill parent" in Ok button it fills everything and Cancel button is not visible anymore.

Your help is appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

On the xml layout add this tag to each button:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

and set the buttons widht to 0px

Comment: set 0px to button width or button layout_width attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Use `weightSum` and `layout_weight` attributes to create the desired view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button android:text="Ok" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button android:text="Cancel" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In case of three buttons `weightSum` is 3.

Comment: Thank you very much, please vote the question I am trying to reach the minimum reputation needed for voting